# агрегация на основе условий

Tags: python, pandas

подскажите как можно посчитать процент колонки 'price' группируя по 'ticker'.Т.е. на сколько процентов цена увеличилась или уменьшилась.Представлял себе так: сгруппировать данные по 'ticker', взять первый и последний индекс группировки - найти разницу между ними.Потом я хотел добавить условие если сумма диффов положительная или отрицательная то приминить pct_change к колонке pcrice.Только вот не понятно как сделать проверку на условие по диффу, и как применить pct_change если цена упала или выросла

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['sel', 3, 'axs'],
                   ['sel', 2, 'axs'],
                   ['sel', 6, 'axs'],
                   ['buy', 8, 'avax'],
                   ['buy', 3, 'avax'],
                   ['sel', 4, 'avax'],
                   ['sel', 3, 'xec'],
                   ['sel', 1000, 'xec'],
                   ['sel', 50, 'xec']],
                  columns=['side', 'price', 'ticker'],
                  index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018/20', end='1/08/2018/20', periods=9)) \
    .reset_index().sort_values('index')

print(df)

df = (df.groupby(['ticker'])['price'].take([0, -1]).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).assign(
    diff_pr=lambda x: x.groupby('ticker')['price'].diff().fillna(0)))
print(df)
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста: Вам требуется для **каждого** объекта (строки) в группе по тикерам подсчитать процентное изменение между текущим и следующим значением price? Или для каждого тикера подсчитать процентную разницу между первым и последним значением price? Пожалуйста, приведите пример данных, которые Вы ожидаете получить на выходе из исходного ДФ.

Comment: Кроме того, цена покупки и цена продажи не обязательно одинаковые, по-нормальному они отличаются в один момент времени. В общем, да, сначала сформулируйте - что вы вообще хотите получить из этих данных. Процент изменения цены между первой сделкой и последней, и не важно покупка это была или продажа, так или нет?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov для каждого тикера посчитать процентную разницу между первым и последним значением price, в дф должно быть две колонки тикер и процентное изменение.К сожалению я сам не знаю какой процент должен получится , так как не знаю как его посчитать при росте или падении цены

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну так как я брал первый и последний индекс внутри группы я хотел сделать так, если последнее значение цены больше чем первое значит цена выросла - считаем процент такто если последний элемент меньше первого , значит цена упала - считаем процент так то

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то, возможно, вам нужно просто это:

```
df.groupby("ticker")["price"].agg(['first', 'last']).T.pct_change().T["last"]*100
```

```
ticker
avax     -50.000000
axs      100.000000
xec     1566.666667
Name: last, dtype: float64
```

**UPDATE**

для получения результата в виде словаря:

```
res = (df.groupby("ticker")["price"].agg(['first', 'last']).T.pct_change().T["last"]*100).to_dict()
```

res:

```
{'avax': -50.0, 'axs': 100.0, 'xec': 1566.6666666666667}
```

Comment: спасибо то что надо

Comment: А, да, так красивше, конечно )

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так, например. Просто вычитаем из последней цены первую, делим на первую цену и умножаем на 100. Получается процент изменения:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['ticker'])['price'] \
     .agg(lambda x: 100*(x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/x.iloc[0]) \
     .reset_index() \
     .rename(columns={'price': 'pct_change'})
df2
```

Вывод:

```
    ticker  pct_change
0   avax    -50.000000
1   axs     100.000000
2   xec     1566.666667
```

Comment: Нет, верните галочку `strawdog`, у него с применением `pct_change`, а у меня подсчёт процента вручную, это не так хорошо )

Comment: я думал можно 2 галки поставить

Comment: @ВадимМотеюнас К сожалению, нет. Плюсы можно на все ответы поставить, а галочку только одну )

Comment: @strawdog, подскажите как можно к вашему коду добавить .to_dict('records') в конце?

Comment: @ВадимМотеюнас возьмите **всю** строку в скобки, и, после закрывающей скобки добавьте ` .to_dict('records')`